# Merge arrays of object with nested arrays of object using JS, lodash or Underscore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, underscore.js, lodash, javascript-objects

I'm trying to merge these 2 arrays of object using lodash javascript library, 
when I do the merge the Subcategories property that contains another array is not merged. 
these are the arrays to be merged

```
var menu1 = [
 {
    "PageName": "Designer",
    "Category": "Designer",
    "LinkTo": "/",
    "SubCategories": []
 },
 {
    "PageName": "CMS",
    "Category": "CMS",
    "LinkTo": "",
    "SubCategories": [
        {
            "Category": "Template DOP",
            "LinkTo": "/sendoutboundmessages"
        }
    ]
}];


var menu2 = [
 {
    "PageName": "CMS",
    "Category": "CMS",
    "LinkTo": "",
    "SubCategories": [
        {
            "Category": "Cataloghi",
            "LinkTo": "/catalogs-manager"
        }
    ]
 }
];
```

I'm trying with lodashJS in this way

```
 const merged = _(menu1) 
.keyBy('PageName')
.merge(_.keyBy(menu2, 'PageName')) 
.values() 
.value();
```

but It doesn't work for the SubCategory property that contains another array

The current output is this :

```
[
  {
    "PageName": "Designer",
    "Category": "Designer",
    "LinkTo": "/",
    "SubCategories": []
  },
  {
    "PageName": "CMS",
    "Category": "CMS",
    "LinkTo": "",
    "SubCategories": [
      {
        "Category": "Cataloghi",
        "LinkTo": "/catalogs-manager"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

and I would like to have this output :

```
[
  {
    "PageName": "Designer",
    "Category": "Designer",
    "LinkTo": "/",
    "SubCategories": []
  },
  {
    "PageName": "CMS",
    "Category": "CMS",
    "LinkTo": "",
    "SubCategories": [
      {
        "Category": "Cataloghi",
        "LinkTo": "/catalogs-manager"
      },
      {
        "Category": "Template DOP",
        "LinkTo": "/sendoutboundmessages"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Tthe `SubCategories` property _is_ being merged, but you want a union of the 2 SubCategories arrays. According to the [Lodash docs](https://lodash.com/docs/#merge) "Array and plain object properties are merged recursively." and "Subsequent sources overwrite property assignments of previous sources".

Comment: ok you are right is there any way to get the union of SubCategory without override ?
I tried the union method and the aoutput is not correct , thanks

Comment: I used a combination of union() and mergewith() in [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60057244/1916816)

Answer (score 4):

You could use LoDash's [mergeWith](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#mergeWith). It's the same as merge but it accepts as customizer function to give you more control over the merge. Try this:

```js
var menu1 = [
 {
    "PageName": "Designer",
    "Category": "Designer",
    "LinkTo": "/",
    "SubCategories": []
 },
 {
    "PageName": "CMS",
    "Category": "CMS",
    "LinkTo": "",
    "SubCategories": [
        {
            "Category": "Template DOP",
            "LinkTo": "/sendoutboundmessages"
        }
    ]
}];


var menu2 = [
 {
    "PageName": "CMS",
    "Category": "CMS",
    "LinkTo": "",
    "SubCategories": [
        {
            "Category": "Cataloghi",
            "LinkTo": "/catalogs-manager"
        }
    ]
 }
];

function customizer(objValue, srcValue, propertyName) {
 if (propertyName == 'SubCategories') {
   return _.union(srcValue,objValue);
 }
}

const merged = _(menu1) 
.keyBy('PageName')
.mergeWith(_.keyBy(menu2, 'PageName'), customizer) 
.values() 
.value();

console.log('merged', merged);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Good solution, the customizer method give more control during the merge. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Only Javascript, Using `map` and `find` methods

```js
var menu1 = [
  {
    PageName: "Designer",
    Category: "Designer",
    LinkTo: "/",
    SubCategories: []
  },
  {
    PageName: "CMS",
    Category: "CMS",
    LinkTo: "",
    SubCategories: [
      {
        Category: "Template DOP",
        LinkTo: "/sendoutboundmessages"
      }
    ]
  }
];

var menu2 = [
  {
    PageName: "CMS",
    Category: "CMS",
    LinkTo: "",
    SubCategories: [
      {
        Category: "Cataloghi",
        LinkTo: "/catalogs-manager"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    PageName: "Devloper",
    Category: "Devloper",
    LinkTo: "/",
    SubCategories: []
  }
];

const doMerge = (data1, data2, key_name) => {
  const merged = data1.map(item => {
    const obj = data2.find(x => x[key_name] === item[key_name]);
    const res = { ...item };
    if (obj) {
      for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
        if (value instanceof Array) {
          res[key] = [...res[key], ...value];
        } else {
          res[key] = value;
        }
      }
    }
    return res;
  });
  const keys = merged.map(x => x[key_name]);
  const other_items = data2.filter(x => !keys.includes(x[key_name]));
  return [...merged, ...other_items];
};

console.log(doMerge(menu1, menu2, "PageName"));
```

Comment: I tried this work fine but If I add a new PageName that is not present in the other array It is not merged

Comment: @cesarandavisa, I see the case you mentioning..missing those items only in menu2. I updated the answer fixing this case.  Let me know if u still see any issue. Thanks.